# Building a static library for glut 3.7 on Windows

Tags: c++, c, static, glut

I've been trying to compile glut as a static library without having to link with glut32.dll on runtime. I downloaded the glut windows source code but when I try to compile (default), I keep getting:

```
Making in glut subdirectory...
        link  /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup@12 -dll  -out:glut32.dll -def:glut.def glut_8x13.obj glut_9x15.obj glut_bitmap.obj glut_bwidth.obj glut_cindex.obj glut_cmap.obj glut_cu
rsor.obj glut_dials.obj glut_dstr.obj glut_event.obj glut_ext.obj glut_fullscrn.obj glut_gamemode.obj glut_get.obj glut_hel10.obj glut_hel12.obj glut_hel18.obj glut_init.obj glut_input.obj glut_joy.ob
j glut_key.obj glut_keyctrl.obj glut_keyup.obj glut_mesa.obj glut_modifier.obj glut_mroman.obj glut_overlay.obj glut_roman.obj glut_shapes.obj glut_space.obj glut_stroke.obj glut_swap.obj glut_swidth.
obj glut_tablet.obj glut_teapot.obj glut_tr10.obj glut_tr24.obj glut_util.obj glut_vidresize.obj glut_warp.obj glut_win.obj glut_winmisc.obj win32_glx.obj win32_menu.obj win32_util.obj win32_winproc.o
bj win32_x11.obj opengl32.lib glu32.lib winmm.lib kernel32.lib  ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib comdlg32.lib winspool.lib
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut32.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x450'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

From what I understand, glut32.lib should be compiled and created in {source}\lib\glut\ but it's not there.

Any help compiling a static library for glut would be appreciated.

***Edit:***

In *Makefile.win*

**Changed:**
`$(link) $(LFLAGS) -out:$(GLUTDLL) -def:glut.def $(OBJS) $(LIBS)`

to

`lib $(OBJS) $(LIBS)`

It generated \lib\glut\glut_8x13.lib not sure what the 8x13 is about but when I tried to link with it, I got some unresolved externals:

```
GPURenderer_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutCreateWindow@4 referenced in function "protected: __thiscall GlobalDecl::OpenGLConte
xt::OpenGLContext(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0OpenGLContext@GlobalDecl@@IAE@II@Z)
GPURenderer_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutInitWindowSize@8 referenced in function "protected: __thiscall GlobalDecl::OpenGLCon
text::OpenGLContext(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0OpenGLContext@GlobalDecl@@IAE@II@Z)
GPURenderer_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutInitWindowPosition@8 referenced in function "protected: __thiscall GlobalDecl::OpenG
LContext::OpenGLContext(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0OpenGLContext@GlobalDecl@@IAE@II@Z)
GPURenderer_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutInitDisplayMode@4 referenced in function "protected: __thiscall GlobalDecl::OpenGLCo
ntext::OpenGLContext(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0OpenGLContext@GlobalDecl@@IAE@II@Z)
GPURenderer_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutInit@8 referenced in function "protected: __thiscall GlobalDecl::OpenGLContext::Open
GLContext(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0OpenGLContext@GlobalDecl@@IAE@II@Z)
GPURenderer_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutSwapBuffers@0 referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall GlobalDecl::OpenGLC
ontext::_executeTest(class GlobalDecl::UnitTest &)" (?_executeTest@OpenGLContext@GlobalDecl@@IAEXAAVUnitTest@2@@Z)
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Please refrain from using GLUT 3.7. [Use FreeGLUT instead.](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: If what I'm trying to do doesn't work, I'll try it with FreeGLUT. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you have something pretty badly munged up in your build setup (or you're using the wrong build setup completely, such as trying to build some samples before you've built the library they use).

To build a static library, you shouldn't be running `link` at all. For a static library, you compile your object files, then use `lib` to put them together into a library. You'd use `link` to build a dynamic library (DLL) or an executable, but not a static library.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jerry. I fixed up the makefile.win in lib\glut, I edited my question with the new output and the line I changed.

Comment: As you've found, it will almost certainly take more than just changing `link` to 'lib` to get a working library. It also looks like your `GPURenderre_test` is *expecting* to link with a DLL, not a static library (the `_imp__xxx` indicates it's trying to import for a DLL).

Comment: Not sure how to solve it. I added `/DGLUT_STATIC_LIB` when building but it still tries to link with a dll. From the nvidia site [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/glut.html), it appears there is a glutstatic.lib but I can't find any documentation on how to build it myself.