# Running OpenGL program in other computers

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, exe

I made a exe file with opengl(visual studio 2012), and I used glut and I used MTd as runtime library(when I use MT it gives LNK2001 errors). But when I try the run it other computers it gives glut32.dll doesn't found error. How can I make glut32.dll built-in my program?

After putting all DLL and library files with exe file in the same folder, I get this error:

[image: Dynamic link error]

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a static library.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856832/building-a-static-library-for-glut-3-7-on-windows) for building GLUT static library.

I think the DLL was compiled for another target, a mix between 32 and 64 bits may occurs.

Search for another lib compiled for 64 bits target.

Comment: I put all dll and library files with exe file in the same folder. But now I get this error.
          http://postimage.org/image/xnx60i4nb/